# django eager loading one-to-many relationships

Tags: python, django, eager-loading

Simple question, I've searched and can't figure this out...

How do I setup eager loading in django?

```
class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)


class Photo(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')


albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user).all()    
for album in albums:
    photos = album.photo_set.all()
    for photo in photos:
        print(photo.name)
        print(photo.photo)
```

I now want to retrieve all albums and all photos, with a single call to the DB.
`albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user).all()`

I've looked at [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) but these looks to be for the reverse (getting the album object at the same time as the photo objects, when querying against the photo object)

Comment: No, `prefetch_related` is exactly what you want.

Comment: according to `debug_toolbar`, I'm executing the same number of queries with `albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user).all()` and `albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user).prefetch_related()`

Comment: oh... I think I needed `albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user).all().prefetch_related('photo_set')`... Doing some more testing.... will check back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the key here was `albums = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user).prefetch_related('photo_set')`

specifically, `prefetch_related('FOO_set')` where 'FOO' is the related object name

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward